# How to separate a case into lines in a cases environment

Tags: cases

I need to divide both the condition and equation part of some cases into lines, as the cases would not fit to text width. I read some similar questions and could not see that solves my problem. A MWE is given.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=22.9cm, paperwidth=8.1cm, margin=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\title{The Title}
\author{Somebody}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{equation}\label{eq:carcost}
c = \begin{cases} 
0           & \mbox{if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss} \\
t(\psi_2-\psi_1)+t_p(\psi_3-\psi1)   & \mbox{if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss}\\
t(\psi_4-\psi_1)+t_p(\psi_5-\psi_1) & \mbox{if if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss}\\
t(\psi_4-\psi_1)+t|\psi_2-\psi_4|+t|\psi_2-\psi_6|+t_p|\psi_3+\psi_5-\psi_1|& \mbox{if if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *might* be what you're after in terms of the presentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\casestext}[2][2in]{\parbox[t]{#1}{\strut\ignorespace #2\strut}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:carcost}
c = \begin{cases} 
0 & \casestext{if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss} \\
t(\psi_2 - \psi_1) + t_p(\psi_3 - \psi_1) & \casestext{if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss} \\
t(\psi_4 - \psi_1) + t_p(\psi_5 - \psi_1) & \casestext[2.5in]{if if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss} \\
\parbox[t]{2.2in}{%
  $t(\psi_4 - \psi_1) + t|\psi_2 - \psi_4|$ \\
  \null\hfill${} + t|\psi_2-\psi_6|+t_p|\psi_3+\psi_5-\psi_1|$} & \casestext{if if aaaa bbbb ssssss ddddd fffff ssssss} \\
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`\casestext[<width>]{<stuff>}` sets stuff in a `\parbox` that is `[t]`op-aligned and of width `<width>`. The default is `2in` when you use `\casestext{<stuff>}`, although you can adjust this with each use by specifying a different length in the optional argument (as is done in the 3rd case). `\strut`s ensure proper vertical spacing between elements.

The use of `\parbox[t]{2.2in}` in setting the equation in the 4th case was to give it a multi-line feel without resorting to much acrobatics.

I've adjusted the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) layout to be more reasonable in this example.

Comment: Can parbox also automatically indent lines after the first line? Also for automatic breaking of equation part, I saw a `breqn` package.

Comment: @ozi: You can use `\newcommand{\casestext}[2][2in]{\parbox[t]{#1}{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1 #2}}` as a definition for `\casetext` which would allow for a hanging indent of `1em`. [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) would not help in this instance.

Comment: I wanted to further push the last term in the last equation down the way you show. It works with a glitch: the last two terms are aligned to the right of parbox, whereas I would want them to be aligned to the left.

Comment: You can just remove the `\null\hfill` in my construction. Otherwise, I'm not exactly sure how you want it displayed. Do you want it spread over three lines?

Comment: Yes I want that last one to spread over three lines. By the way, while playing, I discovered that something like  `\parbox[t]{1.5in}{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1 $....\\....\\...$}` nicely typesets the equation part too. Hence parbox with hangindent and hangafter solved all my problems in this equation. Thanks.

Comment: put a `\strut` at the end of the `parbox` so that the lines aren't so unevenly spaced if there are no descenders on the last line.  a `\strut\ignorespaces` at the beginning wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I absolutely agree! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a tabular for the conditions and `aligned` for the formulas: no need to guess lengths, because you're deciding where to split.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\splitcond}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\title{The Title}
\author{Somebody}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{equation}\label{eq:carcost}
c = \begin{cases} 
0 & 
 \splitcond{if aaaa bbbb ssssss \\ ddddd fffff ssssss} \\[4ex]
t(\psi_2-\psi_1)+t_p(\psi_3-\psi1) &
  \splitcond{if aaaa bbbb ssssss \\ ddddd fffff ssssss} \\[4ex]
t(\psi_4-\psi_1)+t_p(\psi_5-\psi_1) &
  \splitcond{if if aaaa bbbb ssssss \\ ddddd fffff ssssss} \\[4ex]
\!\begin{aligned}[t]
  &t(\psi_4-\psi_1)+t|\psi_2-\psi_4|\\
  &\quad+t|\psi_2-\psi_6|+t_p|\psi_3+\psi_5-\psi_1|
\end{aligned} & 
  \splitcond{if if aaaa bbbb ssssss \\ ddddd fffff ssssss}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The extra spacing is for making better visual separation between the conditions.

[image]

Comment: What is `\!` for?

Comment: @ozi For historical reasons, `amsmath` adds a thin space in front of `aligned` and `gathered`. With `\!` it's removed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that makes the material fit into the very narrow measure specified by the OP. I've abandoned the `cases` environment and substituted in groups of `array` (for math stuff) and `tabular` (for text stuff) environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=22.9cm, paperwidth=8.1cm, margin=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:carcost}
c = \left\{
\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}} 
0           
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
if aaaa bbbb ssssss \\
\ \ ddddd fffff ssssss
\end{tabular} \\[4ex]
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
t(\psi_2-\psi_1)\\
\ \ {}+t_p(\psi_3-\psi1)  
\end{array} 
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
if aaaa bbbb ssssss \\
\ \ ddddd fffff ssssss
\end{tabular}\\[4ex]
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
t(\psi_4-\psi_1)\\
\ \ {}+t_p(\psi_5-\psi_1)
\end{array} 
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
if aaaa bbbb ssssss \\
\ \ ddddd fffff ssssss
\end{tabular}\\[4ex]
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
t(\psi_4-\psi_1)\\
\ \ {}+t|\psi_2-\psi_4|\\
\ \ {}+t|\psi_2-\psi_6|\\
\ \ {}+t_p|\psi_3+\psi_5-\psi_1|
\end{array}
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
if aaaa bbbb \\
\ \ ssssss ddddd \\
\ \ fffff ssssss
\end{tabular}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what do those `@{}l@{}` specify?

Comment: @ozi - the `@{}` elements tell LaTeX not to insert whitespace at the left and right hand ends of the `array` and `tabular` environments, and the `l` ("left") is the alignment specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution that you may find cleaner than some of the previous ones.

It uses package `mathtools`, which provides two environments that I'm using here:

1. `dcases*`, which is supposed to be an improvement over `cases` and
   normally saves you the trouble of switching to text mode in the
   condition, and
2. `multlined`, which splits a mathematical formula in multiple lines.

I'm using a fixed length `parbox` for the condition and the two macros `\shoveright` (for the last line) and `\shoveleft` (for inner lines) to make it look better.  Also, I'm setting the `\multlinegap` length, which controls indentation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=22.9cm,paperwidth=8.1cm,margin=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0.5em}
c = \begin{dcases*}
  0
& \parbox[t]{2.25cm}{%
    if aaaa bbbb \\
    ssssss ddddd \\
    fffff ssssss
  }
\\[3pt]
  \begin{multlined}[t]
    t(\psi_2-\psi_1)+ \\
    \shoveright{t_p(\psi_3-\psi1)}
  \end{multlined}
& \parbox[t]{2.25cm}{%
    if aaaa bbbb \\
    ssssss ddddd \\
    fffff ssssss
  }
\\[3pt]
  \begin{multlined}[t]
    t(\psi_4-\psi_1)+ \\
    \shoveright{t_p(\psi_5-\psi_1)}
  \end{multlined}
& \parbox[t]{2.25cm}{%
    if aaaa bbbb \\
    ssssss ddddd \\
    fffff ssssss
  }
\\[3pt]
  \begin{multlined}[t]
    t(\psi_4-\psi_1)+ \\
    \shoveleft[\multlinegap]{t|\psi_2-\psi_4|+} \\
    \shoveleft[\multlinegap]{t|\psi_2-\psi_6|+} \\
    \shoveright{t_p|\psi_3+\psi_5-\psi_1|}
  \end{multlined}
& \parbox[t]{2.25cm}{%
    if aaaa bbbb \\
    ssssss ddddd \\
    fffff ssssss
  }
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Needless to say, I don't like the result, but this is what you asked for.

[image: result]